# GCP Kubernetes Engine My First Cluster config - when I change the zone, cluster creation fails

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

### EDIT: I found out how to workaround this issue. You can create your own cluster and specify in the pool settings, the machine details and instances you need (instead of using the My First Cluster, which doesn't work under the circumstances described below).

On GCP, when I go to create a Kubernetes cluster, I choose to create My First Cluster (the affordable development option) and I choose Zone: europe-west2, when it tries to create the cluster, it fails with the following error message:

> Subnet "projects/xxxxxxxxx/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/default"
>   does not exist in specified region "europe-west2".

I speculate that while it changes the zone, it does not change the subnet to go with that zone when it's trying to create the cluster, therefore it fails.

I've tried leaving the zone choice alone and customizing post creation, but can't find anywhere that I can change the zone for the cluster, group or individual VMs.

I've tried to create a cluster without using the "My First Cluster", but it does not allow you to specify the number of instances, your machine types and associated parameters.  I've tried customizing the machine types used by the cluster, group and individual VMs but can't figure out how to do this either.

Help appreciated.

Comment: I can'tget the same error, could you please descrive in details? You can't change the zone after create the cluster. You can specify the number of nodes, there is two types of GKE clusters: Zonal and Regional, please see [here](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/types-of-clusters). To customize the instance size you can find under the 'node pool' section. You can use this [article](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/creating-a-cluster) to getting start.

Comment: I know I can't change the zone post create. I also figured out how to change the number of nodes and instance sizes. Thanks for the pointer to the article. I used it but following the directions to create a simple first cluster, changing the zone to eu-west-2, causes that error. I haven't tried it today and I don't have time. I'm evaluating AWS for the rest of the week. Anyway, as you'll see from my edit I did manage to get a cluster configured the way I wanted it. Cheers.

Comment: Hey, do you have any updates about your issue? Was you able to setup the GKE cluster?

Comment: I decided not to bother with My First Cluster route. See my edit at the top of my OP. Since then I have been using AWS and have deleted my GCP project. Thanks for following up.